# Docker - port prevents listening

Tags: networking, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to setup xdebug integration on my docker-based setup.

- I am using Docker for Mac 1.12.0-rc2-beta17 with the "native" docker machine
- I have a container, with xdebug installed, exposing port 9000 and mapping it to the port 9000:

  ```
  $ docker ps
  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                      NAMES
  6950c2a2b05d        app        "/usr/bin/supervisord"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp   app_1
  ```
- When I'm trying to use PhpStorm to listen to the port 9000 for debug connections, I'm getting an error "Cannot listen: port 9000 is busy".

I must precise that I'm a newbie in networks..

Comment: Try executing `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` command and see what app is listening on that TCP 9000 port.

Comment: A port (or a socket, which is an endpoint composed of _ip_address:port_) is not a preemptable resource: at most **one** sole process can access it. The container started uses the port `9000`, hence PhpStorm cannot use it at the same time. Can you show the `docker run` command please?

Comment: @LazyOne: here's the output:

`COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 36299 repptilia   11u  IPv4 0x7faf9785f44d7ab      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)`

Comment: @Auzias: I'm orchestrating the containers via docker-compose. Is there a way to start the container without it blocking the port?

Comment: First of all -- I'm not a Docker user myself .. so cannot give you precise answer. I can only see that some program/service is already listening on TCP 9000 port locally. From what I have seen in other xdebug+docker questions here -- it should not be the case -- the local port should be free. Do not know how to configure it to not to do that .. but here is an idea -- try using 9001 (or any other free port) -- see if it work better (both xdebug and PhpStorm can be easily configured to use that another port).

Comment: As I said: only one process can use a specific [ip:]port. As said @LazyOne try using another port.

Comment: @repptilia Hm.. another thought. How do you open/map those ports? I mean -- which way? Based on `0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp` I assume that local `2222` is mapped for remote (container's) `22`. For HTTP/SSH it has to be from local into container .. but for xdebug it has to be actually other way around ... as it's xdebug who connects to client (PhpStorm in our case).

Answer (score 1):

It dependent how you want to connect via Xdebug

`xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` said that PHP will wait until a HTTP request with GET parameter `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=<IDE_key>`. Then will PHP within the server try to connect back via port 9000 where your PHPStorm is listing. Classic don't call us, we will call you situation.

Now your situation with docker say simple, your container is responsible for port 9000. So PHP will get a loopback and PHPStorm isn't able to use port 9000 because its already used by your docker container.

So skip the assignment of port 9000 to docker, that will fix this situation.

Comment: What do you suggest? That I remove the line "9000:9000" from my docker-compose.yml? If I do that, I'm unable to catch in PHPStorm the breakpoints. If I simply use "9000", docker assigns a random port, which I'm unable to connect to if I change PHPStorm config for the same reasons.

Comment: PHPStorm don't connect to your Docker, it's the opposite PHP will connect back to your host, where your PHPStorm is running and listen on port 9000 that your PHP connect.

Comment: Yeah... took me a while to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

You must bind 9000 port with `--expose` option.

[This is the reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports)

if you are using docker compose sample docker-compose.yml file is here:

```
version: '2'
    services:
      your_app:
         ports:
         - "80:80"
         expose:
         - "9000"
         image: "your-image:tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your container logs to debug:

```
docker logs 6950c2a2b05d
```

or

```
docker logs app_1
```

Add `-f` flags for `tail`-like behavior:

```
docker logs -f app_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I discovered:

- There is no need to expose the port 9000 on a container with xdebug (that seems rather counter-intuitive for me, as I do not exactly understand how my IDE connects to xdebug then).
- I was able to use xdebug using the workaround described in https://forums.docker.com/t/ip-address-for-xdebug/10460/4.