# PhpStorm cannot start Xdebug (to work with Docker)

Tags: phpstorm

I'm running PhpStorm on Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to configure Xdebug to work with Docker. And I followed this guide:

[Zero-configuration Web Application Debugging with Xdebug and PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)

Here's step I did:

Download the Docker Xdebug project source code provided by JetBrains

Edit Xdebug remote host:

[image: Edit Xdebug remote host]

Configure DBGp Proxy (under **Language & Framework** => **PHP** => **Xdebug**) as following:

[image: DBGp Proxy]

Edit Run/Debug Configuration

[image: Run/Debug Configuration]

[image: Run/Debug Configuration]

Edit **Build, Execution, Deployment** for Docker

[image: Build, Execution, Deployment]

Start Docker

[image: Start Docker]

Enable Listening Xdebug Connection

[image: Listening Xdebug Connection]

Check Xdebug info

[image: Xdebug info]

But somehow, I cannot start the Xdebug button (as you can see in the above photo).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well .. you have started the Docker container. Now you need to launch your web app and tell xdebug that you want to debug it. This can be done via specific [bookmarklet ](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) or via xdebug extension for your browser -- either of them will set the xdebug cookie .. so when you reload the page (or click any other link/button on that page so it will load other URL) it will send that cookie to xdebug.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure about the need to map 9000 port in docker as it's xdebug that connects to PhpStorm and not other way around. You may also enable collecting xdebug logs to see what's going on from xdebug side: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: Try to add query paramter "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM" to the URL but not work. Plus, I can even click the debug button.

Comment: You cannot click the debug button (as per your 2nd from last screenshot) because that's for launching Docker only (which in general can be used with any technology: PHP, Ruby, Python, Java ect). For PHP debugging you may create and use "Web App" type of configuration (use it after Docker was launched) or via bookmarklet/extension (like original manual from PhpStorm site is suggesting).

Comment: You may also just use `xdebug.remote_autostart = on` to tell xdebug that it needs to debug every single request (in case if you cannot make it work via xdebug cookie/query parameter).

Comment: You may also look at this Question/Answer -- it's more about not needed 9000 port mapping .. but may give you some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104108/debug-symfony2-in-docker-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/39109956#39109956 ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114976/docker-port-prevents-listening/38176973#38176973

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow the docker container cannot access port 9000 on host machine. By running the following command I fixed the problem:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me couple of hours. :) I ended up using ufw instead though -`sudo ufw allow 9000/tcp comment 'xdebug'`